# Extending class with enum - java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture

Lets say i have two classes A and B, which have theirs internal state represented by enum State. Class B extends A to add new functionality, but it also adds new internal state. To be precise, it adds fine-grained state support, by dividing one of the A`s state into two new states.

I also need to use PropertyChangeSupport to monitor state changes.

Currently I have all states defined in class A in enum State. I have protected methods setState() and getState(). To check on state from the outside, I wrote methods isAvaible(), isComplete(), etc. These methods are present only in appropriate class, depending on their hierarchy and state support.

I realy dont like the idea, having all states defined in parent class. How do I implement this correctly in Java? As far as I know, it`s not possible to use inheritance with enums.

Comment: You can't extend an enum - it would be easier to understand if you could show the structure of your code as code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegation is preferred to inheritance.

```
enum StateA
{
       AVAILABLE , COMPLETE ;
}

class A
{
      private StateA state ;
}

enum StateB
{
     AVAILABLE_TO_PUBLIC ( StateA . AVAILABLE ) , AVAILABLE_INTERNALLY ( StateA . AVAILABLE ) , COMPLETE ( COMPLETE ) ;

     StateB ( StateA sa )
     {
          this . sa = sa ;
     }

     private StateA sa ;
}

class B
{
      private StateB state ;
}
```

Comment: isn't it so, that `AVAILABLE_TO_PUBLIC` and `AVAILABLE_INTERNALLY` would be equal in this modeling?

Comment: @loybert, AVAILABLE_TO_PUBLIC and AVAILABLE_INTERNALLY would not be equal in this model.  `AVAILABLE_TO_PUBLIC . equals ( AVAILABLE_INTERNALLY )` should be false.  This "adds fine-grained state support, by dividing one of the A`s state into two new states."

Comment: ah cool. thought this would have the same internal integer-value, because of the same mapping to `StateA.AVAILABLE`

Comment: Why don't you just combine StateA and StateB into one enum?

Comment: @JamesGoodwin Actually, I like your idea better than my answer.  I interpreted Puty's "dont like the idea, having all states defined in parent class" as meaning he did not want something like that.  But if it were me, I would probably do as you recommend.

Comment: enums are private to the class. I am using public isXXX() methods to determine state from the outside. I was just wondering, if it is possible to make a semantic connection between states of A and B internaly. emory`s answer is exactly what I needed. thx

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to ditch the Enum concept except as something private to class A to help you program it.  A's external state is available through methods like isAvailable() and isComplete().  Class B would extend A but should know nothing of A's enums, though it may have a private one of its own.  If a change needs to affect A's state, and hence A's enum StateA, do it through method calls.

The "state" of an object of either class A or B should be determined, accessed, used, or whatever through its methods, *not* by accessing an enum value.  In other words, an instance of A or B in itself is a complete definintion of state.  It may not *name* the state, as an enum would, but it tells you everything you need to know about what the "state" allows and can do and how it can be changed.

**Alternatively**, you could set up an enum visible to everybody and define it globally.  Then enum StateA is completely independent of class A, solving the basic design problem.  Classes A and B, and others, would then depend on StateA to provide the language they use to communicate with each other and the rest of the system, making for a better design.

I kind of like the first idea better, because, by tweaking A and B, and extending them, you can really fine tune the meaning of each state and even add new states without making a formal announcement.  (Adding a value to an independent StateA is not going to be a big deal, but programmers using StateA might wonder if they should be using the new value--a minor nuisance.)